What's the working principle behind a self-earthed electrical fence voltmeter?
This product can measure the voltage of an electrical fence used to control livestock without any external grounding.
The fence's ground is the earth whilst the voltmeter's ground is the negative pole of the battery.
How does this work?

Fences used in agriculture (and legally compliant fences used to protect property in places such as South Africa) deliver brief energy-limited 3~10ms pulses in the kV range (every second or so). As such, capacitive coupling to the user will work acceptably well in this application, and could help troubleshooting installation or maintenance issues if it is well designed. You're typically only looking for rough indications of the voltage.
There are a few cases where continuous voltage is (or was) used, with potentially lethal effect. Such a device might well read incorrectly or not work at all in such a situation.


How does this work?

very approximatively, if at all. (Don't believe marketing materials.)
I can speculate that you, as the holder of the device, function as high-impedance ground rod. Enough to give your thumb a potential that's close enough to ground to measure whether some kilovolt potential difference is nearby by means of measuring field strength.
My more realistic assumption here, however, is that it makes unmentioned assumptions on the nature of the electrical fence supply, namely that it's either AC or noisy enough to look like AC to someone holding a coil in its vicinity.
In either case, the whole range of 10 different strengths it claims to measure is a wild overstatement of its accuracy.

Electric fences are pulsed - they are not constantly on.  The pulses are relatively short (less than 1 millisecond) so capacitive coupling through the device and the user would work.
